# How to convert integer into date object python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, python-datetime, strptime

I am creating a module in python, in which I am receiving the date in integer format like `20120213`, which signifies the 13th of Feb, 2012. Now, I want to convert this integer formatted date into a python date object.

Also, if there is any means by which I can subtract/add the number of days in such integer formatted date to receive the date value in same format? like subtracting 30 days from `20120213` and receive answer as `20120114`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I would suggest the following simple approach for conversion:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
s = "20120213"
# you could also import date instead of datetime and use that.
date = datetime(year=int(s[0:4]), month=int(s[4:6]), day=int(s[6:8]))
```

For adding/subtracting an arbitary amount of days (seconds work too btw.), you could do the following:

```py
date += timedelta(days=10)
date -= timedelta(days=5)
```

And convert back using:

```py
s = date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

To convert the integer to a string safely, use:

```py
s = "{0:-08d}".format(i)
```

This ensures that your string is eight charecters long and left-padded with zeroes, even if the year is smaller than 1000 (negative years could become funny though).

Further reference: [datetime objects](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), [timedelta objects](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

Comment: but what i m recieving is not a string. its an integer

Comment: well that's not hard, you can use str(x) to convert the integer into a string.

Comment: @peter: ok... thnx for suggestion

Comment: @Uday0119: I added a suggestion how to do it properly even for small years.

Comment: yes @JonasWielicki... thanx for updated information... that is certainly a great help to me...

Answer (score 51):

This question is already answered, but for the benefit of others looking at this question I'd like to add the following suggestion: Instead of doing the slicing yourself as suggested in the accepted answer, you might also use [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) which is (IMHO) easier to read and perhaps the preferred way to do this conversion.

```
import datetime
s = "20120213"
s_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: How about a pandas series consisting of similar strings/integers like "20120203"?

Comment: `df['order_date'] = df['order_date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%Y%m%d'))`

Comment: @1dhiman, this is the format I'm using but I find that it still is very slow on large datasets.  Is there a way to speed it up further in pandas?

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I believe answers the question (Python 3, with type hints):

```
from datetime import date


def int2date(argdate: int) -> date:
    """
    If you have date as an integer, use this method to obtain a datetime.date object.

    Parameters
    ----------
    argdate : int
      Date as a regular integer value (example: 20160618)

    Returns
    -------
    dateandtime.date
      A date object which corresponds to the given value `argdate`.
    """
    year = int(argdate / 10000)
    month = int((argdate % 10000) / 100)
    day = int(argdate % 100)

    return date(year, month, day)


print(int2date(20160618))
```

The code above produces the expected `2016-06-18`.

Comment: I don't know how this works (black magic I suspect) but it works a treat! As it's the only one that actually answers the OP it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

```py
import datetime

timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1500000000)

print(timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

This will give the output:

```
2017-07-14 08:10:00
```

Comment: this was very useful thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.11+ one can use [`date.fromisoformat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat) for this purpose:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

integer_date = 20120213
date_object = date.fromisoformat(f'{integer_date}')
print(f'{date_object - timedelta(30):%Y%m%d}')  # prints 20120114
```

> Changed in version 3.11: Previously, this method only supported the format YYYY-MM-DD.

### Performance

A timeit on my machine shows that `fromisoformat` is around 60 times faster than using `datetime` class, and about 7 times faster than `strptime`. Here is the code:

```py
import datetime as dt
from timeit import timeit


strptime = dt.datetime.strptime
fromisoformat = dt.datetime.fromisoformat
datetime = dt.datetime

s = "20120213"
assert datetime(int(s[0:4]), int(s[4:6]), int(s[6:8])) == fromisoformat(s) == strptime(s, '%Y%m%d')

strptime_time = timeit('strptime(s, "%Y%m%d")', globals=globals())
fromisoformat_time = timeit('fromisoformat(s)', globals=globals())
datetime_time = timeit('datetime(int(s[0:4]), int(s[4:6]), int(s[6:8]))', globals=globals())

print(f'{strptime_time/fromisoformat_time=}')
print(f'{datetime_time/fromisoformat_time=}')
```

Result:

```
strptime_time/fromisoformat_time=60.46678219698884
datetime_time/fromisoformat_time=7.008299761426674
```

(Using CPython 3.11.2 and Windows 10)